# SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55b0d4f9b8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer, on Marshmallow and a below devices

Tags: android, loopj, sslexception

I am getting this error **SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55b0d4f9b8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer** in Marshmallow version andandroid versions below marshmallow. I have tried all solutions available on Stack Over flow and other blogs but nothing could help in my case. Code works fine on Nougat. I have tied SSLSOCKETFatory, TLSSOCKETFACTORY and all other possible solution i am using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ library for communication with service.